# Wrapper Div glitch/ is moving while page is loading to be centered

Tags: jquery, css

I have a generated image slider by jQuery [orbit plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider) can be checked [link to slider on my site](http://dev.digitup.se/pilatessoder/). My problem is experiencing a half-second glitch on the page while the jQuery code executes to generate the div that accomades the images. The wrapper is centered by css code:

```css
div.orbit-wrapper {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

The wrapper seems to move a bit from the left to reside in the center of the page. I'd prefer the wrapper not to display at all until the JavaScript has run to avoid the problem. Any ideas are highly appreciated!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hiding it with `display:none;`, which takes it out of the content flow, simply make it invisible with this, `style="visibility:hidden;"` or this...

```css
#myWrapperDiv {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Then after the page is done loading (including the images), reveal it using this...

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#myWrapperDiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Your container `<div>` with class `.orbit-wrapper` is being dynamically generated by the Orbit script with CSS `visibility:visible;` already applied so it's never really hidden by your CSS at all.  The dynamic DOM manipulation by the script is over-riding your CSS.

The solution is to apply `style="visibility:hidden;"` to a new wrapper `<div>` surrounding everything...

```
<div id="myWrapperDiv" style="visibility:hidden;">

    <div id="featured">
        <img src="http://dev.digitup.se/pilatessoder/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/pilates-soeder-bilder-2011-01.jpg" />
        ... {snipped} ...
    </div>

</div>
```

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#myWrapperDiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Comment: Tried your approach and still no luck. I have add the CSS to the wrapper in CSS file and added the script as suggested. I left it live in case you want to check... thanks again

Comment: @digitup:  That's because your element with class `.orbit-wrapper` is being dynamically created by the Orbit script with `style="visibility:visible;"` already applied to it.  To workaround it, you'll have to simply surround the whole thing in another wrapper `<div>` and use my suggestion above.

Comment: @digitup:  Glad to hear it.  It's what I do on all my image sliders.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently.  Try adding `display: none;` to the container div.  That will prevent it from showing that split-second flash.  You can change `none;` to `block;` through jQuery after loading completes with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#whateverSelector').show();
});
</script>
```

You can either put this at the end of the document before the `</body>` or (better yet) before the `</head>`.

Perhaps the `none;` is being over-written somewhere in the CSS. Try adding the style inline to see if you can sort-of "force" it to work. This this in the HTML: `<div class="orbit-wrapper" style="display:none;">...`  I hope that helps.

Comment: thank you so much for your time. I have added the inline style as well but I still get this glitch. Very strange. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the `div` with `display:none`, in a style tag on the `div`, and once all the JavaScript is run just change it back to `display:block`.

With jQuery you can just do `$(".orbit-wrapper").show();` once the page is done loading in the `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` code block.

Comment: The problem with `display:none;` is that it takes the element out of the content flow so anything around it moves when you change it back to `display:block;`.  Also `document.ready` fires when the DOM is loaded but not necessarily after all the images or assets have loaded.